# Converting RSA encryption code from php to python

Tags: php, python, django, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to connect to a api in my python app .
so the api documentations comes with php and asp sample code but no python

I'm pretty good with php but have no experience with encryption ... I'm trying to re-write python code for the api using php sample .

They use this class for RSA

```
 https://github.com/AlaFalaki/Pclass/blob/master/libraries/rsa.class.php
```

(Since its a RSA lib im guessing python RSA lib would take care of this part ) :

```
static function rsa_sign($message, $private_key, $modulus, $keylength) {
  $padded = RSA::add_PKCS1_padding($message, false, $keylength / 8);
  $number = RSA::binary_to_number($padded);
  $signed = RSA::pow_mod($number, $private_key, $modulus);
  $result = RSA::number_to_binary($signed, $keylength / 8);
  return $result;
 }
```

Here is the problem php sign function takes 4 arguments uses some internal functions ... But python rsa has 3 and one of them is just the hash method !

```
rsa.sign(message, priv_key, hash)
Parameters: 
  message – the message to sign. Can be an 8-bit string or a file-like object. If message has a read() method, it is assumed to be a file-like object.
     priv_key – the rsa.PrivateKey to sign with
     hash – the hash method used on the message. Use ‘MD5’, ‘SHA-1’, ‘SHA-256’, ‘SHA-384’ or ‘SHA-512’.
```

i've tried little experiment to see if i get same output

so i've singed a simple `text` string in php

```
echo base64_encode(RSA::rsa_sign(sha1("test"),$private_key,$modulus,$key_length));
```

i got

something like

```
dKt+4CocMNdIrtYCUr8aZykR8CpfmYUEEVONMuAPlM5mR70AoyzMhGjcEGB9fKLVC4rr5xt66w2ZmHqWO+p834rJmo9Fj57udRSY5wFs0VokMF2S2SMFn5WTYYmMBuWciRzZybWnfXcSIyp9Ibi28cdwl5hXJOMpXEJrNQLFy2s=
```

next i extracted private_key , public_key , modulus from a xml file that they gave me with api containing my keys ( using the same  RSA class ) like

```
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlRsakey);

        $this->modulus = RSA::binary_to_number(base64_decode($xmlObj->Modulus));
        $this->public_key = RSA::binary_to_number(base64_decode($xmlObj->Exponent));
        $this->private_key = RSA::binary_to_number(base64_decode($xmlObj->D));
        $this->key_length = strlen(base64_decode($xmlObj->Modulus))*8;
```

i made a python dictionary with them

```
def keys():
        obj = {
            'modulus' : "14417185111734127374105962730273......." ,
            'public_key' : "61111" ,
            'private_key' : "3739752306322843055980611965983321761993....." ,
            'key_length' : 1024 ,
        }
        return obj
```

and i've tried to sign a string in python

```
def sign(request):
    api  = keys()
    message = 'test'
    crypto = rsa.sign(message.encode('utf-8'), api['private_key'] , 'SHA-1')
    b64 = base64.b64encode(crypto)
    return HttpResponse(b64)
```

but i get :

```
'str' object has no attribute 'n'
```

and that was my failed experiment

As i said i dont have any experience with encryption or rsa .... i want some advice from someone who worked with this stuff .

Should i give up and use php to encrypt/decrypt ?

Comment: My gut says that PHP and Python have implemented things ... differently. I can't say how. My gut also says (perhaps from a biased point-of-view) that the Python lib is statistically more likely to hove to the standards than PHP. If this is a one-time conversion, I suggest whatever is expedient, move your data over, and be done with it. Life is too short, etc.

Comment: @PeterRowell well it's tow-time conversion connection and verifying data after user came back ... im going to use php for now but i'll keep eye on this question ... i think right now problem is my `private_key`  , php uses a string for pk but python needs something complex like dic  , that's why i get the error when i pass my php private key to python rsa function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They use this class for RSA
>
> ```
> https://github.com/AlaFalaki/Pclass/blob/master/libraries/rsa.class.php
> ```

My advice: Run away screaming.

RSA is a mine field of security issues. There are a lot of things that you can screw up. So when someone *implements the primitives* in PHP using the BC extension, that's the security equivalent of standing naked in front of a firing squad and expecting to have no holes.

- Encrypting with PKCS1 padding [allows near-trivial message decryption](http://framework.zend.com/security/advisory/ZF2015-10)
- Screwing up your parameters [can completely remove all security from your crypto](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/70059600123/saltstack-rsa-e-d-1)
- Home-grown RSA is ripe with [side-channel attacks](https://ssrg.nicta.com.au/projects/TS/cachebleed)

### Recommendation: [Use Libsodium](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/how-to-safely-implement-cryptography-in-any-application) Instead

There are both PHP and Python bindings available for libsodium.

#### If RSA is Unavoidable...

If you really want RSA and not modern cryptography, check out [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib).

```
<?php
use 
$rsa = new RSA();

// HIGHLY RECOMMENDED FOR SECURITY:
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(RSA::ENCRYPTION_OAEP);
$rsa->setMGFHash('sha256');

$rsa->loadKey($yourPEMencodedRSAPublicKey);
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt($plaintext);
```

If you're going to encrypt with RSA, you **must** follow [these cryptography rules](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-11-cryptographic-right-answers.html). If your library doesn't let you follow these rules, it's time to switch to libsodium.

Also note that encrypting large messages with RSA is both slow and dangerous: There's usually nothing preventing messages from being reordered, which can be really bad.

The solution here is: Use symmetric-key authenticated encryption and use RSA to encrypt the public key. That's what [EasyRSA](https://github.com/paragonie/EasyRSA) does, although I'm not aware of any Python equivalents, so I can't recommend that as a solution.

**Of course, if you use libsodium's `crypto_box` API you don't have to worry about that!**

Comment: thanx , im using their api so they decide what kind of encryption i should use so thats that ... thanx for a great answer i got some reading to do and i'll get back to you

Comment: I think phpseclib does OAEP by default, which would make the `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(RSA::ENCRYPTION_OAEP);` line redundant.